# || statement in a coffeescript switch statement

Tags: coffeescript, switch-statement

How can I use an || (or) statement in a coffeescript switch? Need that because its the same assignment for different types.

```
switch type
  when 'pdf'
    icon = 'file-pdf-o'
  when 'mpg' || 'mpg4' || 'flv' || 'mp4'
    icon = 'film'
  else
    icon = 'file'
```

This doenst work. It just checks for the first string `'mpg'` How can I achieve that correctly?

Comment: This example is [on the CoffeeScript homepage](http://coffeescript.org/#switch) (see `when "Fri", "Sat"`)

Comment: @Mathletics ohh. I actually have seend this example but didn't read up to this part. And was already sad that I had to consult SO for such a simple question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use comma separated lists to cause the switch statement to 'fall-through' its options. This is the same as using an empty case with no break in vanilla JavaScript.

```
switch type
  when 'pdf'
    icon = 'file-pdf-o'
   when 'mpg', 'mpg4', 'flv', 'mp4'
     icon = 'film'
   else
     icon = 'file'
```

compiles to:

```
switch (type) {
  case 'pdf':
    icon = 'file-pdf-o';
    break;
  case 'mpg':
  case 'mpg4':
  case 'flv':
  case 'mp4':
    icon = 'film';
    break;
  default:
    icon = 'file';
}
```